# A small proportion of the non-zero eigenvalues lies near zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Problem:** We consider a sequence $(A_n)_{n\ge 1}$ of matrices such that

1. $A_n$ is a $n\times n$ matrix with integer co-efficients,
2. The sum of the absolute values of entries of any row is at-most $M$.

For every $\delta>0$, let $N_{\delta}(A_n)$ denote the number of eigenvalues of $A_n$ of modulus strictly between $0$ and $\delta$. Prove that

1. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A_n$, then $|\lambda|\le M$.
2. Show that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every $n\ge 1$,
   $$N_{\delta}(A_n)\le \epsilon n $$

*My attempt:* I could prove the first part using triangle inequality and stuff like that. But am completely stumped on the second part. I tried to proceed by contradiction and constructing sequence of eigenvalues, but that didn't seem to lead anywhere. I would appreciate some hints towards the correct direction, rather than a complete solution.

Comment: Using the same notation for matrices and integers is confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ and $q$ be the proportions of eigenvalues of $A_n$ whose moduli lie inside $(0,\delta)$ and $[\delta,M]$ respectively. The number of zero eigenvalues of $A_n$ is thus $n(1-p-q)$.

If $A_n$ is not nilpotent, then the the coefficient $c_{n(1-p-q)}$ of $x^{n(1-p-q)}$ in the characteristic polynomial of $A_n$ is a nonzero integer and
$$
|c_{n(1-p-q)}|
=\prod_{0<|\lambda_i(A_n)|<\delta}|\lambda_i(A_n)|
\prod_{\delta\le|\lambda_j(A_n)|\le M}|\lambda_j(A_n)|
\le\delta^{np}M^{nq}
\le\delta^{np}M^{n(1-p)}.
$$
Hence we must have $\delta^{np}M^{n(1-p)}\ge1$, i.e., $M\ge\left(\frac{M}{\delta}\right)^p$. It follows that $p\le\frac{\log M}{\log(M/\delta)}$ whenever $\delta<M$. So, if we pick any $\delta_0<M$ such that $\frac{\log M}{\log(M/\delta_0)}\le \epsilon$, we will have $p\le\epsilon$ and hence $N_{\delta_0}(A_n)=np\le n\epsilon$.

If $A_n$ is nilpotent, we also have $N_{\delta_0}(A_n)=0\le n\epsilon$. Therefore $\delta=\delta_0$ is a feasible choice for all $n$ and all integer matrices $A_n$ whose spectral radii are at most $M$.